# Symfony2 Login: Authenticate a user by 3 criteria

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm trying to make a symfony2 login that makes a user provide 3 credentials to login, e.g.

username

regnumber

password.

I'm using a custom entry provider, form the book. in this there is a class

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->getQuery();

    try {
        // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
        // if there is no record matching the criteria.
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();

    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        $message = sprintf(
            'Unable to find an active User "%s".',
            $username
        );
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Is there a way to pass more variables to this method e.g. `loadUserByUsername($username, $regnumer)`
I could then query for the extra data,

does anyone have any advice?

thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no easy way to change loadUserByUsername.  You could write your own custom authentication manager http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html . I found that to be very challenging though once you have it working then you do have complete control over authentication.  The default system does send an AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS event when the user/password is authenticated.  You could try listening to this event and then applying your regnumber authentication.  Have not tried it myself but it should work.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the advice. I was thinking that the custom authentication handler was the way to go. I will give it a go and report back.